# Python remote attach in Jetbrains Fleet

Tags: python, docker, debugging, jetbrains-fleet

Is it possible to use Jetbrains Fleet and debug a process via remote attach?
For example, to debug inside a docker container?

Remote attach currently seems to exist only via attachment to Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **Remote Attach** action for Python (a related request for this: [Attach to Remote Process](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33998/Attach-to-Remote-Process)),

but it is **possible to debug Python on a remote machine in Fleet**:
You can [install and run a Fleet backend on a remote server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/install-on-a-remote-machine.html) where your code resides, e.g. for macOS:

**Install Fleet on a remote host**

```
curl -LSs "https://download.jetbrains.com/product?code=FLL&release.type=preview&release.type=eap&platform=macos_x64" --output fleet && chmod +x fleet
```

**Run Fleet on a remote host**

```
./fleet launch workspace -- --auth=accept-everyone --publish --enableSmartMode
```

and then [connect to it from](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/connect-to-workspace.html) the client machine, e.g. for macOS:

From JetBrains Fleet

1. Press `⌘⇧K`.
2. Start typing **Join Session** and select the corresponding action when it appears in the suggestions.
   [image: Searching for the Join Session action using the Go to popup]
3. Specify the workspace ID or URL and press `↵`.

[image: Entering the connection URL in the new window]

Wait until the connection is set up.

And then run and [debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/debug-python-code.html) the remote code as usual.